Cauchy product of zeta function

$\zeta(s)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}; s \in \mathbb{C}$.

For $Re(s) > 1 $, we have that the above series converges absolutely. And in this case, I wrote the Cauchy product of $\zeta(s)$ by itself as:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^s}\frac{1}{(n+1-k)^s}
\end{align*}
But now I can't seem to find a way to arrive at the result
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d(n)}{n^s}$$
where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.
Any suggestions?

$k^s(n+1-k)^s=\left(k(n+1-k)\right)^s.$ So how many times in the Cauchy product is the denominator $m^s?$

In general:, for nice enough functions $f,g,$ $$\left(\sum_{n}\frac {f(n)}{n^s}\right)\sum_{n} \frac{g(n)}{n^s}=\sum_n\frac{\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)g(n/d)}{n^s}$$

@ThomasAndrews, for each divisor $d$ of $m$; $m=dq$ and if we could write $q$ as $(n+1-d)$ for some $n$ or vice-versa, we should have $d(m)$, but I'm afraid I didn't understand the whole idea quite well

@JP; $m^s$ appears every time $k(n+1-k)=m$, which is every time $k$ is a divisor of $m$ over various $n$'s.

The way you wrote it is not really useful here - the grouping should be on denominators with same $m$ and since $1/n^s \times 1/k^s=1/(nk)^s$ the terms with same $m$ count the divisors; for power series one uses the form you wrote as there powers add when multiplied

What this reveals is that different ways of writing the same problem can make different things more or less obvious. And this particular form is not very helpful to recognize the intended identity.

The Euler product of $\zeta(s)$ is
$$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p\in prime} \frac{1}{1-\frac1p}$$
$\zeta(s)^2$ is therefore
$$\zeta(s)^2 = \prod_{p\in prime} \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac1p\right)^2}$$
$$ = \prod_{p\in prime} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k+1}{p^k}$$
As the definition of $d(n)$ is
$$d({p_1}^{a_1}\dots{p_m}^{a_m})=(a_1+1)\dots(a_m+1)$$
then
$$\zeta(s)^2=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{d(n)}{n^s}$$
